# How does the Python conditional operator workaround work?

Tags: python, indexing, boolean, conditional-operator

From what I have read, I found that a built-in ternary operator does not exist (I will be happy to know more about it.).

I found the following code as a substitute:

```
def val():
    var = float(raw_input("Age:"))
    status = ("Working","Retired")[var>65]
    print "You should be:",status
```

I couldn't understand how this code works; can anyone explain me how actually the code is working? I am also interested to know why the ternary operator doesn't exist; any references or links about this will be ore useful.

I'm running Python 2.6.4 on Windows Vista.

Comment: The ternary operator was added to Python in version 2.5

Comment: -1: Please do not call it "THE" ternary operator.  It's just a conditional operator, and it happens to be one (of many) ternary operations.  Other ternary operations include `pow(x,y,z)`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but typically an operator is something like "+" or "%" or (in this case) "if". ie: not a function. I don't think that pow would be considered a ternary operator, it's just a function with three inputs. (Ternary operatION, yes. operatOR, no.) In many languages inline conditionals such as this are the only operator that takes three inputs, and as such are THE ternary operator (for that language), so it's really not incorrect. Wiki to the rescue!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator

Comment: The `(x, y)[bool]` construct is the standard idiom for this before 2.5. Its disadvantage compared to `y if bool else x` is that `x` and `y` are always calculated, whereas the ternary operator will short-circuit one of the terms.

Comment: @Toji: the "operation" (the word I used) and "operator" distinction is too subtle for me.  Lots of languages have lots of operators in lots of notations.  Unary and binary operators/operations are common.  But to call this (and only this) operator/operation "ternary" is goofy.  What about higher-arity operators?  It's a poor term, and one that can easily be avoided by calling it the conditional operator, because that's what it is.  It happens to have be ternary (or having an arity of 3) but that's not the defining characteristic.

Comment: @Toji: But Python has other ternary operators: `__setitem__(self, key, value)`, `__setattr__(self, name, value)`.

Comment: @Toji I think someeone gone and changed the Wiki article you've linked to (or at least how it redirects). It now disagrees with you. What do you want to be it was done by an SO user after reading this? (FWIW I've also mainly heard this referred to as "the" ternary operator which now feels natural to me)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Python has a construct that is sort of like the ternary operator in C, et al. It works something like this:

```
my_var = "Retired" if age > 65 else "Working"
```

and is equivalent to this C code:

```
my_var = age > 65 ? "Retired" : "Working";
```

As for how the code you posted works, let's step through it:

```
("Working","Retired")
```

creates a 2-tuple (an immutable list) with the element "Working" at index 0, and "Retired" at index 1.

```
var>65
```

returns True if var is greater than 65, False if not. When applied to an index, it is converted into 1 (True) or 0 (False). Thus, this boolean value provides an index into the tuple created on the same line.

Why hasn't Python always had a ternary operator? The simple answer is that Guido van Rossum, the author of Python, didn't like/didn't want it, apparently believing that it was an unnecessary construct that could lead to confusing code (and anyone who's seen massively-nested ternary operators in C can probably agree). But for Python 2.5, he relented and added the grammar seen above.

Comment: I recall sitting through an OSCON *keynote* where Guido talked about why he *didn't* put the ternary operator into Python.  Think about it, a large audience of diverse developers and techies and the speaker is going on about the minute details of a language specific feature that was old news 30 years ago and *didn't implement*.  No attempt to make a broader point.  The most boring keynote I've ever experienced.

Answer (score 9):

Python (2.5 and above) does indeed have a syntax for what you are looking for:

```
x = foo if condition else bar
```

If `condition` is True, `x` will be set to `foo`, otherwise it will be set to `bar`.

Examples:

```
>>> age = 68
>>> x = 'Retired' if age > 65 else 'Working'
>>> x
'Retired'
>>> age = 35
>>> y = 'Retired' if age > 65 else 'Working'
>>> y
'Working'
```

Comment: Just a heads up that this is only available in version 2.5 or later.  There is nothing similar in older versions.

Comment: @Pace yes, although the asker mentions they are using 2.6.4. Just added a note for clarity though.

Answer (score 8):

because True casts to 1 and False casts to 0 so if var = 70

```
("Working","Retired")[var>65]
```

becomes

```
("Working", "Retired")[1]
```

a nice little shortcut ... but I find it can be a little confusing with anything but a simple condition, so I would go with TM's suggestion

```
"Retired" if var > 65 else "Working"
```

Answer (score 7):

#### indexing into a list

The use of

```
[expression_when_false, expression_when_true][condition] # or
(expression_when_false, expression_when_true)[condition]
```

takes advantage of the fact that in Python True equals (but isn't!) 1 and False equals (but isn't!) 0. The expression above constructs a list of two elements, and uses the result of *condition* to index in the list and return only one expression. The drawback of this method is that both expressions are evaluated.

#### and-or shortcuts

Since the creation of Python, there was a form of this operation:

```
condition and expression_when_true or expression_when_false
```

This takes a shortcut and evaluates only one expression, but has a bug-prone drawback: the *expression_when_true* **must not** evaluate to a non-true value, otherwise the result is *expression_when_false*. `and` and `or` are "short-circuiting" in Python, and the following rules apply:

```
a and b #→ a if a is false, else b
a or b  #→ a if a is true, else b
```

If *condition* is false, then *expression_when_true* is never evaluated and the result is *expression_when_false*. OTOH, if *condition* is true, then the result is the result of (*expression_when_true* or *expression_when_false*); consult the table above.

#### ternary conditional operator

Of course, since Python 2.5, there is a ternary conditional operator:

```
expression_when_true if condition else expression_when_false
```

The strange (if you are accustomed to the C-like ternary conditional operator) order of the operands is attributed [to many things](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/); the general intention is that *condition* should be true most of the time, so that the most common output comes first and is most visible.

Answer (score 2):

### Short-circuit boolean expressions

There is also an option to short-circuit logical operations:

```
>>> (2+2 == 4) and "Yes" or "No"
'Yes'
>>> (2+2 == 5) and "Yes" or "No"
'No'
```

In your example:

```
>>> (int(raw_input("Age: ")) > 65) and "Retired" or "Working"
Age: 20
'Working'
>>> (int(raw_input("Age: ")) > 65) and "Retired" or "Working"
Age: 70
'Retired'
```

Read more about this technique in [Charming Python: Functional Programming in Python, Part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-prog/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.6 and up:

```
print "You should be {0}.".format("retired" if var>65 else "working")
```

In Python 3.1 and up:

```
print ("You should be {}.".format("retired" if var>65 else "working"))
```

Comment: In your first example, Python 2.5 doesn't have that style of string formatting.

Comment: Ah, thanks; I took this info from Pace's comment to a different answer - you're right, `.format()` was introduced in 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

in the code that you posted the following line is emulating ternary:

```
status = ("Working","Retired")[var>65]
```

here tuple `("Working","Retired")` accessed with an index `[var>65]` which evaluates to either `True` (`1`) or `False` (`0`). When it's accessed with index `0`, `status` will be `'Working'`; if index is `1` then it'll be ``Retired'`. It's a fairly obscure way to do conditional assignment, use the normal ternary syntax that was introduced in py2.5 as was said.

Answer (score 0):

this is the form with the python ternary operator

```
def val():
    var = float(raw_input("Age:"))
    status = "Retired" if var > 65 else "Working"
    print "You should be:",status
```

the code you showed is a bit tricky: it creates a two elements tuple whose elements are at position 0 and 1. to select the right element it uses a condition which return a boolean but booleans in python are integers so you can use it as *special* indexes (they can be either 0 or 1).

Comment: Oops. Your ternary condition is reversed. A good example of why you'd choose to use another construct for clarity.

Comment: Unfortunately simple boolean logic like this is ALWAYS easy to inadvertently flip, no matter how it's formatted. I don't think that the ternary really has anything to do with it.

Comment: jmanning2k: I reverted the answer to its initial form, since it was already correct. Think of it as an English phrase: "You should be retired if older than 65, else working."

Answer (score 0):

There was originally no ternary operator because "Explicit is better than implicit", and it was seen as unpythonic. I don't like python's ternary op too much, either, but it exists:

```
x = foo if condition else bar
```

as shown by TM.

As for `status = ("Working","Retired")[var>65]`, 
`var > 65` returns a boolean value: either True or False; however, Python treats boolean types quite weakly: `True` is `1` and `False` is `0` in some contexts. You can check it out by doing `>>> True == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
status = ("Working","Retired")[var>65]
```

This line works as a ternary operator because the expression `var>65` returns 1 or 0, depending on whether `var` is bigger than 65 or not.  So if `var>65`, then the line becomes this:

```
status = ("Working","Retired")[1]
```

that is, the second element of the sequence `("Working","Retired")`.  It looks odd but not if you write it like this instead:

```
status_sequence = ("Working","Retired")
status = status_sequence[1]
```

so `status = "Retired"`.

Similarly, if `var<=65` then it becomes

```
status = ("Working","Retired")[0]
```

and `status = "Working"`.

Answer (score 0):

Only the "status =" line of that code implements something like the ternary operator.

```
status = ("Working","Retired")[var>65]
```

This creates a two-element tuple, with strings 'Working' at index 0, and 'Retired' at index 1.  Following this, it indexes into that tuple to pick one of the two items, using the results of the expression `var > 65`.

This expression will return True (equivalent to 1, thus picking 'Retired') if the value of var is greater than 65.  Otherwise it will return False (equivalent to 0, thus picking 'Working').

There is a key difference between this approach and the ternary operator, however, although it doesn't matter in your particular example.  With the tuple-indexing approach, both values are evaluated but only one is returned.  With the ternary operator, only one of the two values is actually evaluated; this is referred to as "short-circuit" behaviour.  It can matter in cases like this:

```
status = funcA() if var > 65 else funcB()
status = (funcB(), funcA())[var > 65]
```

In the first case, either funcA() is called *or* funcB() is called, but never both.  In the latter case, both are called first, and the results are stored in the tuple -- then only one is picked and the tuple is discarded.

This is especially important to understand if either funcA() or funcB() have "side-effects", meaning they change other data as they execute.

Answer (score 0):

trying to give a complete answer based on the answers given here.

the way you found (please don't use this one because it is not very readable):

```
def val():
    var = float(raw_input("Age:"))
    status = ("Working","Retired")[var>65]
    print "You should be:",status
```

using the python 2.5+ syntax:

```
def val():
    var = float(raw_input("Age:"))
    status = "Working" if var>65 else "Retired"
    print "You should be:",status
```

using the other common method still preferred by some people:

```
def val():
    var = float(raw_input("Age:"))
    status = var>65 and "Working" or "Retired"
    print "You should be:",status
```

<del>i personally tend to use the last since the order of the operands is the same as the C ternary operator.</del>

**EDIT:**
found some problems with the last approach (thx Roberto Bonvallet).
from wikipedia:

> this code would break if op1 could be
>   a "falsy" value (None, False, 0, an
>   empty sequence or collection, …) as
>   the expression would return op2
>   (whether it was truthy or falsy)
>   instead of the (falsy) op1

so my final suggestion would be to **use the 2.5+ ternary operator** since it is simple, readable and offers short-circuit behavior.

Comment: I can't believe people keep suggesting the and-or hack. They're not equivalent, since the and-or trick has some nasty corner cases where it doesn't work as expected. (I'm not downvoting you because you're answering for the sake of completitude, but I'm commenting also for the sake of completitude to warn all you to DON'T DO IT.)

Comment: The and-or hack has one sole advantage, which is that it allows short-circuit behaviour.  The risks are generally too great to use it though (the biggest being that the programmer doesn't understand it, and the second biggest being that the *next* programmer won't understand it).

Comment: The second and third examples in this Answer have 'Working' and 'Retired' swapped, which gives the wrong answer.  Try this:    `status = "Retired" if var>65 else "Working"`.