# What does this python syntax mean?

Tags: python

I was looking through some code for a library called django-cas and spotted this line:

```
protocol = ('http://', 'https://')[request.is_secure()]
```

What exactly does this line mean/do?

Comment: Duplicate of this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947030/how-does-the-python-conditional-operator-workaround-work.  It's just a matter of understanding the rewritten if-else.

Answer (score 8):

It picks one of two values based on the boolean outcome.

- `('http://', 'https://')` is a tuple
- `request.is_secure()` produces a boolean result, `True` or `False`.
- A boolean is a subclass of `int`, and `True == 1`, `False == 0`.

Thus, if the request was secure (used SSL encryption, over `https`) the `protocol` will be set to `https://` too.

More recent versions of Python (2.5 and up) allow for a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), which would be more readable:

```
protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
```

Comment: +1 for being the first to add the more conventional way to do this. (I had the page opened and edits keep happening everywhere)

Answer (score 2):

This just selects `0` or `1` index element from the tuple, as
`True` equals `1`, and `False` equals `0`

```
>>> secure = True
>>> ('http','https')[0]
'http'
>>> ('http','https')[1]
'https'
>>> ('http','https')[secure]
'https'
>>> ('http','https')[False]
'http'
```

However, a cleaner way of doing this would be :

```
protocol = "http" if request.is_secure() else "https"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to the following

```
protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
```

I prefer this to clever indexing tricks.

Answer (score 1):

`request.is_secure()` will evaluate to `True` if the connection is secure ([HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure): HTTP over TLS) or `False` if non-secure (standard HTTP).

So, if `request.is_secure()` is `True`, then:

```
protocol = ('http://', 'https://')[request.is_secure()]
# Will resolve as:
protocol = ('http://', 'https://')[True]
# Which is:
protocol = ('http://', 'https://')[1]
# And results in.
protocol == 'https://'
```

Or, if `request.is_secure()` is `False`, then:

```
protocol = ('http://', 'https://')[request.is_secure()]
# Will resolve as:
protocol = ('http://', 'https://')[False]
# Which is:
protocol = ('http://', 'https://')[0]
# And results in.
protocol == 'http://'
```

- NOTE: The boolean constants `True` and `False` resolve to the integers `1` and `0` respectively because [`bool` is a sub-class of `int`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool).

The purpose of this is to determine what HTTP scheme (secure or non-secure) to use for links.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clever *ternary operator* in python. Based on the boolean result it will pick one of those two strings.

If `False` (0) will pick the first one and if `True` (1) the second one.

Look it like this:

```
>>>('http://', 'https://')[False]
'http://'

>>>('http://', 'https://')[True]
'https://'
```

It can also be achieved like this:

```
protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protocols = ('http://', 'https://')
```

This creates a two-item tuple of the two possible protocols

```
secure = request.is_secure()
```

This returns True or False, equivalent to 0 or 1

```
protocols[secure]
```

This picks the correct element that matches the security

Answer (score 0):

`request.is_secure()` returns either `True` or `False`.
Thus if it's `True`, it selects the item in index 1 from the list (`True` equals 1), else it selects the item in index 0 from the list.

Thus, `http` and `https` point to not secure and secure respectively.